# P values for demographic variables in a paper -- which test was performed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value, case-control-study

I'm reading a paper and they have a table describing the distribution of demographic variables by case and controls, but there is also a Ps column. I assume this is a p-value, but what are they testing for? A significance difference between the distributions? How would you calculate this? thanks, example table below:

```
Income        control (%) case (%)  Ps
<10,000       38 (23.8)   32 (39.5) 0.0005
10,000-19,999 41 (25.6)   25 (30.9)
>20,000       81 (50.6)   24 (29.6)
```

Comment: @DC2 Linking the paper would be very helpful.

Comment: There are a number of possibilities; it's hard to be certain from the information given. It *might* be a p-value for a chi-squared test of homogeneity of case-vs-control proportions across the three income categories, but it might be something else. [Actually calculating the chi-square I get a p-value ten times as big, so maybe not a chi-square]

Comment: It looks like a Chi-Squared Contingency test was performed. In that case, there will be only one P-value for the entire contingency table.

Comment: Please give a complete reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some judicious searching I have found the paper, it's:

Schiff MA, et al. (2001),
"Serum carotenoids and risk of cervical intraepithelial neoplasia in Southwestern American Indian women",
*Cancer Epidemiol Biomarkers Prev*., Nov; 10(11): 1219-22.

The p-value you gave in your question is not correct, it should have been 0.005:

[image: Image of table from paper showing p-value is actually 0.005]

(This error made it considerably more difficult to figure out!)

As mentioned in comments above, one possibility for a test there was to test for homogeneity of proportion (/a test of independence) of case vs control across income categories, but I ended up discounting that possibility because the p-value didn't match. But now that we have the correct value from Table 1 in the paper, when we compare with the chi-square p-value calculated on the same counts, we do get a close match:

```
 chisq.test(matrix(c(38,41,81,32,25,24),nr=3))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  matrix(c(38, 41, 81, 32, 25, 24), nr = 3)
X-squared = 10.576, df = 2, p-value = 0.005052
```

As we see, this is the same p-value (to the number of figures given) so it moves from a possibility to a highly likely possibility that this is the test that was performed. [It's possible it was something similar, like a G-test or a Fisher test, I haven't computed p-values for those. The way to be certain that this is what was done is to ask the authors.]